# Handle coupons and payments for custom products

Tags: joomla-extensions, payment-processing, coupon

I have an existing 1.5 Joomla site that uses solidcart by Joozen. It basically integrates zencart inside Joomla. Solidcart is no longer supported and stuck at the 1.5 version. I am working to launch a 3.0 website but I need to be able to integrate checkout for my products. The product selection is customized so I do not want to use a normal shopping cart. I need to be able to build my own product selection page along with it's options. What would be great is if I had something that had built in coupon creation and management that integrated with the checkout and payment process under a Joomla login. I looked through extensions but could not find anything that seemed would meet that. Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: You could try virtuemart, it has recently added a release candidate version for joomla 3.

Comment: I was hoping to find something that wasn't so heavy.  I don't need all the e-commerce front end just the back end processing and coupon piece.  I will create my own products.